# How to display specific column from CSV file in php?

Tags: php, file, csv, fgetcsv

I have one CSV file which has 10 columns(A to J). Now, my problem is that I want to display only data from the column name E on the screen using PHP.

How would I read and display that one column from the CSV file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fgetcsv()` function. It takes a line of a csv file and expands it into an array. The following script wil print out the fourth column of each line of the csv file. You can simply change the `$col` variable to print out a different column.

```
<?php

//column to print, E would be 5th
$col = 5;

// open the file for reading
$file = fopen("yourfile.csv","r");

// while there are more lines, keep doing this
while(! feof($file))
{
    // print out the given column of the line
    echo fgetcsv($file)[$col];
}

// close the file connection
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/csv/port_cat_sidebar.php on line 13......I think here is the error - echo fgetcsv($file)[$col];.....can you please give me exact output as i mention in question?

Comment: Double check all your semicolons.

Comment: After some modification this is the code....Can you please check this?     <?php

//column to print, E would be 5th
$col = 5;

// open the file for reading
$file = fopen("portfolios.csv","r");

// while there are more lines, keep doing this
while(! feof($file))
{
    // print out the given column of the line
    echo fgetcsv($file)[$col];
}

// close the file connection
fclose($file);
?>

Comment: Okay no problem. If i want to display cell no [B][5] then what is the code to display same output.